# Rails serving .svg as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rqrcode-rails3 gem in my application. I want to generate a qr code in SVG or PNG format. I am using Rails 3.0.7 with Ruby 1.8.7. The problem I have is that rails is forcing .svg file to render as html instead of xml by using the application layout to render it.

I tested the gem in a test application with rails 3.2.3 and it works. But in my real application somehow I cannot get it to work.

Any idea how I can get it work?

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.svg { render :qrcode => request.url, :level => :l, :unit => 10 }
      format.png { render :qrcode => request.url }
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the full filename of your layout?

Comment: I have a view qrcode.html.erb and a layout qrcode.html.erb in layouts. I even created a view qrcode.svg.erb but it still deaults to qrcode.html.erb view.

Comment: @user1570144 what is the url and the Content-Type for the request perhap it because your content-type is text/html and there is format.html return at the top of format.svg